# change route to website - Gateway timeout

Tags: ubuntu, route, web-services, request

My website has to connect to a web service, but sometimes it is receiving a Gateway Timeout, sometimes it works allright.
I'm guessing the route it's going on is wrong. Right now, the traceroute is this one:

```
user@user:~$ sudo traceroute -n -w 2 -q 2 -m 10 www.grupoj3.com.br
traceroute to www.grupoj3.com.br (200.155.23.38), 10 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  200.155.0.121  0.400 ms  0.214 ms
 2  200.219.215.70  0.384 ms  0.410 ms
 3  187.0.192.7  6.097 ms  6.087 ms
 4  187.33.27.138  6.264 ms 187.33.27.114  6.128 ms
 5  200.155.23.29  6.058 ms  6.005 ms
 6  * *
 7  * *
 8  * *
 9  * *
10  * *
```

Anyone has any idea how I can fix this? Is it wrong really? I kind of did not like networks on college. :) Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a routing issue, or the host or a proxy is intermittently down.

If the point at which your traceroute stops is in the same AS as the remote host, chances are they are having trouble with their hosting.  If it is in the same AS as you, chances are your ISP is having trouble.  If it is in the middle, there is a routing issue caused by one peer along the way.

You have effectively no control over this type of issue, except that you can change ISPs.  You could contact your ISP with this information (though in my experience it is very hard to interest ISPs in this type of problem).